# Network adapters marked with (*) in ipconfig /all

Tags: vpn, network-adapter, ipconfig

This feels like a good place to ask.

What does the (*) specify in this `ipconfig` example?

I am using Shrew and Cisco VPN clients, and for some reason, Shrew doesn't work (i can connect but then can't see anything in the remote network)

[image]

Comment: Maybe some insight here>>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ipconfig

Comment: No I already tried. It says that when used in command it does what it usually does, make a broad search with (*) replacing the exact name

Answer (score 0):

The asterisks in my display refer to adapters (NIC) not currently in use.  Right click on Network and select Properties, then Adapter settings. I see Bluetooth, VPN and LAN red X not connected (and they are not connected - I am on wireless). So the asterisk just means not connected.

Comment: no in my case red X transposes to Media disconnected in ipconfig, and no (*)

Comment: Yes.  Media is disconnected if not in use.  Same here

Comment: I dont have * on the physical ports that are indeed disconnected (Bluetooth and LAN like in your example). (*) must be some kind of indicator for a virtual NIC, but what kind

Comment: Virtual NICs may also be disconnected.  My virtual NICs are machines and I have two additional machines running so VMnet8 is actually connected.  No worries here and nothing is wrong with what you see. It will changes as connections come and go as well.